# JavaFX TableView ComboBox String Converter

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to add a ComboBox into the TableView but for some reason I cannot make the conversion. Behind the scenes, I want to make the conversation if the value is 
0 then it should display 'free' if the value is 1 then it will say 'taken' in the ComboBox, and once the user changes the value in the ComboBox 
it will save its integer value.

I am not sure how to add the converter and it gives the following error at `event.getNewValue()`:

> cant convert int to string.

Any help where I am doing wrong?

```
private final IntegerProperty mode;   
public int getMode() {
    return mode.get();
}
public void setMode(int mode) {
    this.mode.set(mode);
}
public IntegerProperty modeProperty() {
    return mode;
}

Set<String> modeList = new HashSet<>();
modeList.add("Free");
modeList.add("Taken");

var converter=modeConverter();
TableColumn<Review, String> modeCombo = new TableColumn("Mode");
modeCombo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("mode"));
modeCombo.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(converter); //How to apply the converter.
modeCombo.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableList(modeList))));

modeCombo.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
    mode.setOperationMode(event.getNewValue()); //Method cannot be applied java.lang.String. But I already make the conversatin via modeConverter
});

...

private StringConverter modeConverter() {
    return new StringConverter<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Integer object) {
            if (object == 0) {
                return "FREE";
            } else {
                return "Taken";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Integer fromString(String string) {
            if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("free")) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [all the methods available in ComboBoxTableCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overloaded method:

> [forTableColumn​(StringConverter converter,
>                                                                                ObservableList items)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html#forTableColumn(javafx.util.StringConverter,javafx.collections.ObservableList))

Please note that ComboBox backing list should contain 0, 1 instead of Free, Taken. The converter is responsible for displaying 0 as Free and 1 as Taken.

Also, the TableColumn should be of type `<Review, Integer>` instead of `<Review, String>`.

In your code, you can do something as follows:

```
ObservableList<Integer> modeList = FXCollections.observableList(0, 1);
TableColumn<Review, Integer> modeCombo = new TableColumn("Mode");
modeCombo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("mode"));
modeCombo.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(converter, modeList)));
```

Once your basic type is fixed, the following should work:

```
modeCombo.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
   mode.setOperationMode(event.getNewValue());
});
```